# How to move second image to center of div [responsive design]?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

How to move second image to center of div [responsive design] ?

https://jsfiddle.net/ydufL6o2/

I have 3 image,

first image position is left. It's ok.

third image position is right. It's ok.

But i have issue on second image, how can i move second image to center [responsive design] ?

```
<div style="position: relative;width: 100%;height: 40px;text-align: center;background-color: #373737;padding: 10px 0px;">
<div style=" display: block; position: relative; margin: 4px 0px; float: left; margin-left: 1.5%;">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="/* margin: 16px auto; */height: 31px;border: none;width: 31px;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
<div style=" display: block; position: relative; margin: 4px auto; float: left; ">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="width: 31px;height: 31px;border: none;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
<div style=" display: block; position: relative; margin: 4px 10px; float: right; margin-right: 1.5%; ">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="/* margin: 16px auto; */height: 31px;border: none;width: 31px;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using inline styling less.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make element centered you can use `margin: 0 auto`, however - since your element is blocked it will take 100% of the width.

You can change that element to be `inline-block` and then use the `margin: 0 auto` to do the trick.

```html
<div style="position: relative;width: 100%;height: 40px;text-align: center;background-color: #373737;padding: 10px 0px;">
<div style=" display: block; position: relative; margin: 4px 0px; float: left; margin-left: 1.5%;">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="/* margin: 16px auto; */height: 31px;border: none;width: 31px;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
<div style=" display: inline-block; position: relative; margin: 4px auto; ">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="width: 31px;height: 31px;border: none;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
<div style=" display: block; position: relative; margin: 4px 10px; float: right; margin-right: 1.5%; ">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="/* margin: 16px auto; */height: 31px;border: none;width: 31px;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
</div>
```

Regarding the comment about the 100%-width input in the center - check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/62b6prwo/

Comment: And this issue https://jsfiddle.net/ydufL6o2/3/ , how to set width of input to 100% ?

Comment: If this is your case you should have said it in the first place :) There is a big difference between the elements and the solution here is to use a grid system for that (like bootstrap or something alike).

Comment: @peatwedty, Check the update, I added a jsfiddle regarding the comment about the `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the: `float:left;`
from the division and adjust the margin and padding to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```html
<div style="position: relative;width: 100%;height: 40px;text-align: center;background-color: #373737;padding: 10px 0px;">
<div style="
                                    display: block;
                                    position: relative;
                                    margin: 4px 0px;
                                    float: left;
                                    margin-left: 1.5%;
                    ">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="/* margin: 16px auto; */height: 31px;border: none;width: 31px;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
<div style="
                                    display: block;
                                    position: absolute;
                                    left: 0;
                                    right: 0;
                                    margin: 4px 0 4px ;
                    ">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="width: 31px;height: 31px;border: none;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
<div style="
                                    display: block;
                                    position: relative;
                                    margin: 4px 10px;
                                    float: right;
                                    margin-right: 1.5%;
                    ">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="/* margin: 16px auto; */height: 31px;border: none;width: 31px;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
</div>
```

It sets the middle div to absolute, allowing you to move it to the center of the wrapper, by using `left: 0;` and `right: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

This works, play around with the margin settings so you can position the third image without using negative top margin.

```html
<div style="position: relative;width: 100%;height: 40px;text-align: center;background-color: #373737;padding: 10px 0px;">
<div style=" display: block; position: relative; margin: 4px 0px; float: left; margin-left: 1.5%;">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="/* margin: 16px auto; */height: 31px;border: none;width: 31px;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
<div style=" display: block; position: relative; margin: 4px auto; text-align: center; ">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="width: 31px;height: 31px;border: none;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
<div style=" display: block; position: absolute; right: 10px; margin-top: -35px; margin-right: 1.5%; ">
<img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="/* margin: 16px auto; */height: 31px;border: none;width: 31px;" height="31px" width="111px">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:left;` on the middle div, and change the margin to `margin:auto;`.

Change the display on the divs from `display:block;` to `display:inline;` so they remain next to one another.

Change the middle image to `position:relative;` and add `top:4px;` to position vertically.

```
    <div style="position: relative;width: 100%;height: 40px;text-align: center;background-color: #373737;padding: 10px 0px;">
  <div style="
                                    display: inline;
                                    position: relative;
                                    margin: 4px 0px;
                                    float: left;
                                    margin-left: 1.5%;
                    ">
    <img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="/* margin: 16px auto; */height: 31px;border: none;width: 31px;" height="31px" width="111px">
  </div>
  <div style="
                                    display: inline;
                                    position: relative;
                                    margin:auto;

                    ">
    <img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="width: 31px;height: 31px;border: none; position:relative; top:4px;" height="31px" width="111px">
  </div>
  <div style="
                                    display: inline;
                                    position: relative;
                                    margin: 4px 10px;
                                    float: right;
                                    margin-right: 1.5%;
                    ">
    <img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg" style="/* margin: 16px auto; */height: 31px;border: none;width: 31px;" height="31px" width="111px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Please see:
https://jsfiddle.net/ydufL6o2/4/

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**

Inline styling is **NOT** the way to style elements. It should be done in the stylesheet or in the `style` tags in the `head` part of the HTML. Here is the proper code.

Basically I cleaned up your code **A LOT** by adding IDs and classes.

What you had to do is remove the `float: left` property from the middle `div`.

After that, you have to change the `display: block;` to `display: inline-block`, as I did in the `childDiv` class `div`s.

That solves the problem, as shown in this snippet.

```css
#parentDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #373737;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
.childDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 4px 0px;
}
img {
  height: 31px;
  border: none;
  width: 31px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">
  <div class="childDiv" style="float: left; margin-left: 1.5%;">
    <img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv">
    <img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="childDiv" style="float: right; margin-right: 1.5%;">
    <img src="https://thumb-cc.s3.envato.com/files/189105725/KMRS%20Thumbnail.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```